# Change color of UISwitch appwise

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

I am using `UISwitch` in iOS 3 to make a switch element in my app. It has default color set to blue, but I want to change its color to brown.

How can I choose a different color for the `UISwitch` element in iOS 3?

How can I choose a different color for the `UISwitch` element in a modern iOS app (iOS 5+)?

Comment: Currently being discussed on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387055/8239061

Answer (score -5, accepted):

For a modern iOS XX version skip the answer as it has zero relevance lately.
Still here?
In iOS 3. You can't. But you know… people are landing here because of rank, and comments containing other versions and stuff so…

The fifth iOS release now allows a documented way of doing this: with the property `onTintColor`.

```
UISwitch *s = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
s.on = YES;
s.onTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:s];
[s release];
```

produce this

[image: It's a thing that was requested that looks a color]

**Edit:** I have no idea why someone would come through and roll back the answer to limit it to the question only while not doing the same to all the answers.

**Edit more:**
In iOS 3 you had to use some undocumented feature. There used to be a link about that [here](http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/10/14/alternate-uiswitch-colors/) but it broke. And if you did that your app might get rejected because of changing the color.

It kind of starts with this, which should be enough for you to find it somewhere else:

```
UISwitch *aSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:someRectangle];
[aSwitch setAlternateColors:YES];
//Do something with aSwitch
[aSwitch release];
```

I can't recommend it. And that turns out unpopular.

Comment: This solution is OK for an enterprise application. However, now that iOS 5 supports tint color, shouldn't this be the accepted answer?

Comment: So. Normally, when the QUESTION states it's using iOS 3, then it doesn't matter what you can or can't do in another iOS. Feel free to ask it again, better, and move whatever answer that's right for iOS whatever the question is about, to there. Or you know, search better. At this point the fact that someone came through and answered the wrong question here dropping the wrong version keyword into the page is driving search where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 43):

Finally, with iOS 5 you can change the color of the switch with the property `onTintColor`.

```
UISwitch *s = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
s.on = YES;
s.onTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:s];
[s release];
```

produces this:

[image]

Comment: @AnkitSachan: As per community rules, you should mark this question as accepted, if its worked for you. For me and many others this is a working solution.

Comment: @Fry how did you set the "I"

Comment: @kozla13 from iOS 7+ it's a configuration in Setting.

Answer (score 7):

For a global change for all UISwitch elements in Swift 3, use the appearance proxy:

```
UISwitch.appearance().onTintColor = UIColor.brown
```

under the AppDelegate `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are limited to text values of On/Off or 0/1 for a UISwitch.  You can customize the color by using tint.  For further customization I would suggest something like what's been posted above going with a completely custom solution

ex. `[mySwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:175.0/255.0 blue:176.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];`

source: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

EDIT: For iOS3, you are limited to a custom implimentation, I would suggest swapping two buttons with custom images.  In later iOS versions you are given much more control and built in customization options.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the custom UISwitch control that I built to allow me to change the background color of the control. You could use the same method to change the text, the font, or the text color very easily.

http://www.homick.com/posts/custom-uiswitch-control

The code is available on GitHub and includes a PSD that is used to build three different PNG files that the control uses. You can modify the contents of the psd to recreate the PNG files in whatever format you like. Swap those into the control and away you go.

This gives a lot more options than just orange and blue.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3:

```
var mySwitch : UISwitch = ...
mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.blue
```

Comment: I think you mean Swift 3. (cannot edit because of too few characters)