# UISwitch's color

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I can change UISwitch's color with below code but always color is yellow how to change color to another color?

```
UISwitch *switch1=[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 121, 94, 27)];
[switch1 setAlternateColors:YES];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [change color of switch in iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720376/change-color-of-switch-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 29):

Finally, with iOS5 you can change the color of the switch with the property `onTintColor`.

```
UISwitch *s = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
s.on = YES;
s.onTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:s];
[s release];
```

produce this

[image]

I hope this help !

Answer (score 2):

Check [this page](http://github.com/homick/iPhone-Snippets/tree/master/General) for a project with a custom switch.

Answer (score 1):

From the [UISwitch reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html), "The UISwitch class is not customizable." So you can't change the appearance of UISwitch.

Comment: look at Fry's answer.

Comment: @DenisKozhukhov, when this answer was made it was not possible. Please see the dates.